# CR2008: display cross-tab with no spanning

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm writing a report that can be exported to excel and using cross tabs. I have two groups A and B, where A can contain multiple subgroups of B.

When I drag A and B into the rows on the left, the outermost group A spans multiple rows depending on how many subgroups of B there are.

Is there a way to have group A repeat itself for every row of B? Like a full table without any of that cell-spanning.

Comment: Would you post some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you since it means you can't do Totals on the outer group, but here is one possible solution. Create one formula that concatenates both group A and group B values together and use that in your cross tab instead. In this example, I had to use a format string to get the numerical-to-string values to sort correctly.

[image: Without group totals]

EDIT: Never mind, I fixed it so you can have the outer group Totals, too. Just leave the outer grouping the way it was, but replace the inner grouping with your new concatenated string (via the formula you just made). You'll have to suppress the outer group header (shown in the screenshot) and format the grid lines to look nicer or overlay a whiteout box, though (not shown in screenshot).

[image: With group totals]

Comment: that is a good idea, though the client has requested to omit repetitive data (for clarity), hence why I am using separate groups.

Comment: @Keikoku What is the repetitive data?

Comment: In your example, you concatenated the 1 and the False/True together. In my case, it'd be the 1 with possibly many different subgroups. That becomes distracting quickly.

Comment: @Keikoku Isn't that what you're looking to do? "Is there a way to have group A repeat itself for every row of B?" In my example, Group A (the numbers) are repeating for every row of Group B. I guess I'm confused - Using my example, can you tell me what you want to display instead?